# Questions about AWS EC2 auto scaling and load balancing

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have little bit knowledge of `AWS EC2`. Previously I have bought a `mx3large` instance and did all my necessary installations on the server and cloned my code there but didn't map domain to the system.

Now my client wants to implement auto scalling and load balancing. I have read about those that auto scalling is to add/subtract instances with respect to traffic and load balancing is to balance loads between instances.First correct me if I am wrong.

Now I want to ask

1. If I auto scale some instances, do I need to do installations on all instances or some one instance? If one then what will be my primary instance?
2. As mentioned above, I have already bought an instance where I did my all installations. But that instance is currently stop. Will I remove that instance when I will be using auto scaling?
3. What are the prices. If I bought a instance of $0.28/hour, will I have to pay number of instances * cost for number of time they are activated?
4. On which instance I will be cloning my code, ssh to connect and all related operations?
5. Load balancing will automatically start working with my auto scall instances?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions make me think you still need to read a lot of "getting started" guides, but I'll do my best to answer your questions:

1) If I auto scale some instances, do I need to do installations on all instances or some one instance? If one then what will be my primary instance?

R: All instances, none will be a "primary instance". They will all be treated equally

2) As mentioned above, I have already bought an instance where I did my all installations. But that instance is currently stop. Will I remove that instance when I will be using auto scaling?

R: The Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) will detect that your instance is not healthy and will stop sending request to that instance

3) What are the prices. If I bought a instance of $0.28/hour, will I have to pay number of instances * cost for number of time they are activated?

R: You pay for the time they are in running state and for the time the ELB is running (it can't be stopped, only deleted)

4) On which instance I will be cloning my code, ssh to connect and all related operations?

R: On every instance. The ideal case is when all of them are identical

5) Load balancing will automatically start working with my auto scall instances?

R: yes, assuming you have correctly configured the autoscaling group with the ELB